Error Loading Large .RDataTmp File into RStudio
I am encountering an error when trying to load a .RDataTmp file into RStudio. The file is approximately 87 MB in size. Here are the steps I've taken and the issues I've encountered:
I have tried moving and renaming the file, but the error persists.
I was able to open the file with an editor, indicating it is not corrupted.
When attempting to open the file in RStudio via "Open File," I receive a message stating "too large as it exceeds 5MB."
Could the file size be causing this issue? What steps can I take to successfully load this large file into RStudio?
Thank you for your assistance!
load("~/dat_envir.RDataTmp")
Error in load("~/dat_envir.RDataTmp") : 
  Read error from connection

